# Error de certificado SSL en Tomcat: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: java, tomcat, certificado-ssl

Buen dia, cordial saludo.

Recurro nuevamente a este medio (como siempre lo hago cuando "ya no encuentro mas solución") para presentarles un problema que estoy teniendo al momento de instalar un certificado SSL en el servidor tomcat.

He adquirido hace unos dias un certificado SSL en la plataforma Comodo el cual me envió al correo 4 archivos comprimidos en un .zip.

1. AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
2. COMODORSAAdtrustCA.crt
3. COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
4. www_midominio_com.crt

He agregado los cuatro certificados antes mencionado al keystore con el que creé el código CSR y por ultimo este es el código que he colocado en el archivo server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" alias="mialias" 
    keystoreFile="/conf/mikeystore" 
    keystorePass="micontrasena"/>
```

Sin embargo, sigo recibiendo por parte de los navegadores que el certificado no es confiable. Cabe destacar que en anteriores ocasiones tuve un tiempo mi dominio enlazado con cloudflare el cual funcionó perfectamente hasta que decidí adquirir un certificado con diferente proveedor.

Agradezco de antemano a quien me pueda ayudar con dicho problema porque es para un servidor en producción el cual no he podido restablecer su servicio por el problema presentado.

Comment: ¿Qué navegadores? Si son todos similares (mismo navegador, versión similar) ¿Puede ser que estos navegadores simplemente no tengan instalado alguno de los CAs? Sería lo primero a revisar.

Comment: Pero no creo que sea problema del navegador, sino del certificado en tomcat. Porque si es el navegador, ¿entonces como haría para instalar el certificado a todos los usuarios de mi servicio? Seria casi que imposible.